# Does temperature in a vessel with same top surface area as a earthern pot and same amount of water have same temperature of water?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, evaporation

Many people answer the question 'why earthern pot keep water cool?' In this way

'Because it has large surface area that allow more evaporation than other vessels we used to keep, so more cooling.'

But, Is it only reason?

Because suppose I take a normal metal or plastic vessel whose top surface area is equal to full curved surface area of pot. And that vessel and pot contain same amount of water. So overall vessel has same surface area as pot at its top(open ) and same volume of water.

So does the water in that vessel have same temperature as pot due to equal amount of evaporation?

If yes, than why we use such pot not a vessel like i have mentioned?

Comment: Do you really want to use a container with a top surface equal to the  complete surface of an earthen container? (an what about all the dust an insects on your open top surface? ..but if you only consider the temperature you can do it.

Comment: So temperature would be same?, just because of some other practical reason we use pot?

Comment: Having used a “botijo” as a child in Spain I can attest that cooling is due to water transpiring through the porous baked clay and evaporating from the outer surface.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botijo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can increase the surface area of the water in a plastic vessel directly exposed to the air so that it is the same as the total surface area of the earthen pot plus the exposed area, and perhaps achieve the same temperature (I say perhaps because you may need to factor in different amounts of heat transfer by conduction and radiation).

But to do so you must then alter the other dimensions of the vessel as well to have the same volume. That means you may have to considerably increase the "footprint" of the vessel, not to mention, as @trula pointed out, increasing the amount of drinking water exposed to dust and dirt.

To put some numbers on it, let the earthen pot vessel be a cylinder of 8 cm diameter, 20 cm high, and open at the top. This means, if my math is correct, a total surface area including the top of about 600 cm$^2$, and volume about 1000 cm$^3$.  That in turn means a plastic vessel open at the top would need a diameter of about 28 cm to have the same area for evaporative cooling. In order for the volume to be the same, its height would be about 16 mm.

So, as a practical matter, would you rather have a vessel 8 cm in diameter and 20 cm high occupying space, or a vessel 28 cm in diameter and 16 mm high occupying space and containing dirtier water to drink.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, please can you answer this one too.               https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/669945/315475

Comment: U say that i must take some factors into consideration like conduction and radiation, can you give an example how these 2 can affect temp. Between pot and vessel?

Comment: It becomes too much of complex problem to deal with here.

Comment: Ok, have u checked that link que?

Comment: I read it but to be honest I don't understand it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130264/discussion-between-anshika-singh-and-bob-d).